# Unable to escape double quotes(") from search text in elasticsearch?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I am having an elasticsearch query as given below:

```
{
    "query_string": {
    "query": "*metallic ladder 80\"W",
    "default_operator": "or",
    "fields": [
         "attributes.attributevalues"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Here I am trying to escape double quotes from the search text.

For this I am getting "Failed to parse query [*metallic ladder 80"*]"

I am searching for this product in my application but due to this error, I am getting no results.

It will be a great help if any one suggests some way we can inclue double quotes in a searchterm while using elasticsearch.

Full error is as below:

```
    {
     "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
    "type": "query_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse query [*metallic ladder 80"*]",
    "index": "finefoodindex"
    }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
    "shard": 0,
    "index": "finefoodindex",
    "node": "aVgE3oxST3KcP3I--b-pIQ",
    "reason": {
    "type": "query_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse query [*metallic ladder 80"*]",
    "index": "finefoodindex",
    "caused_by": {
    "type": "parse_exception",
    "reason": "Cannot parse '*metallic ladder 80"*': Lexical error at line                 1, column 22. Encountered: <EOF> after : "\"*"",
    "caused_by": {
    "type": "token_mgr_error",
    "reason": "Lexical error at line 1, column 22. Encountered: <EOF> after                 : "\"*""
    }
    }
    }
    }
    ],
    },
    "status": 400
    }
```

Comment: Could you please include the code that you are using for the operation?

Comment: index the field as not_analyzed and use a match query, escaping quotes like \"

Comment: Don't you need to escape the backslash as well?

Comment: The above issue is regarding double quotes only. Rest of the special characters gets handled in my code.

Comment: What I meant was this `"*metallic ladder 80\\"W"`

Comment: I tried with @blackmamba solution. That gave me result for 'metallic ladder 20"W' also.

Comment: Then tried @val's solution, it gave me exact result. It seems we need to double escaping of double quotes. Thanks.

Comment: I came here looking for NEST code and all I saw was JSON...

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
{
    "query_string": {
        "query": "*metallic ladder 80\\\"W*",
        "default_operator": "or",
        "fields": [
            "attributes.attributevalues"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please pay more attention to formatting - your answer is unreadable at the moment. Use the preview to check that what you post is what you want people to see.

Comment: Your answer helped me! using Java and ES integration example: QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("*\\\"" + searchTerm + "\\\"*").field("som_field")

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments above, you need to also escape the backslash character, like this:

```
{
    "query_string": {
    "query": "*metallic ladder 80\\"W",
    "default_operator": "or",
    "fields": [
         "attributes.attributevalues"
            ]
        }
    }
```